Decomposing correlation matrices into vectors which have pairwise bivariate normal entries to apply test of significance?
This question originally was posted at MathOverflow, but I deleted it there, since it might be a better fit for here:
A semantic space is a finite set $X$ with a symmetric, positive semi-definite function $k: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$k(x,x) = 1 \forall x \in X, -1 \le k(x,y) \le 1 \forall x,y \in X$$
A correlation matrix $R$ has the following characteristic properties:
symmetric, positive semi-definite, $R_{i,i} = 1 \forall i = 1, \ldots, n$, $|R_{i,j}| \le 1 \forall i,j$
Thus, we can consider the Gram matrix $G = (k(x,y))_{x,y \in X}$ in a semantic space as a correlation matrix. This allows us to,
consider individual entries $G_{x,y}$ in the Gram matrix as correlation values $\rho_{x,y} := G_{x,y}$ and perhaps apply a statistical test which
tests the hypothesis: $\rho_{x,y} = 0$. To apply the test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Testing_using_Student's_t-distribution), it must first be clarified how many degrees of freedom are available, and whether
the underlying random variables are pairwise bivariate normally distributed. The test size with $df = m-2$ degrees of freedom, where $m$ is the 'number of individuals' would be:
$$t = \frac{\rho_{x,y}}{\sqrt{\frac{1-\rho_{x,y}^2}{m-2}}}$$
If one is given a positive-definite Gram matrix, then one can perform Cholesky decomposition or KPCA to obtain vectors $\phi(x), x \in X$ which
could be interpreted as random vectors with the property that:
$$\left < \phi(x), \phi(y) \right > = k(x,y) = \rho_{x,y}$$
The dimension $d$ of these vectors would then correspond to the number of individuals $m$ and in Cholesky decomposition or also in KPCA this number would be greatest with $m=n$.
Thus, the degrees of freedom would be $df = n-2 = |X| - 2$.
For every Gram matrix, there can be different vectors that realize this matrix.
The question that arises is, whether there is a method to find the vectors $(\phi(x), \phi(y))$ so that they have pairwise bivariate normally distributed entries.
Then one could apply the t-test from statistics with confidence, without ever having to practically find these vectors.
Application:
As described in these notes, one could do, with the help of the statistical test above, quantitative/probabilistic logic, which depends on some perspective.
